# Scraping data from a table using scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I am learning scrapy for data extraction. I tried to extract the `DISPENSARY NAME` and `ADDRESS` information from the webpage- https://arizonamedicalmarijuanaclinic.com/dispensaries/.
I am finding it difficult to extract the informationit is in tabular format. I tried-

```
scrapy shell 'https://arizonamedicalmarijuanaclinic.com/dispensaries/'
data = response.css('table').extract()
```

But this does not extract the table not it gives any output, I have tried other combinations also but none has worked. Can anyone give me a hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the table is dynamically rendered by JS that scrapy won't access

You should try [Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) or [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/). if you want you can use this [api](https://arizonamedicalmarijuanaclinic.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp_ajax_ninja_tables_public_action&table_id=42643&target_action=get-all-data&default_sorting=old_first) to extract the data easily using [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) like this.

```
import requests
import json
url = 'https://arizonamedicalmarijuanaclinic.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=wp_ajax_ninja_tables_public_action&table_id=42643&target_action=get-all-data&default_sorting=old_first'

import requests

headers = {
    'authority': 'arizonamedicalmarijuanaclinic.com',
    'pragma': 'no-cache',
    'cache-control': 'no-cache',
    'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
    'accept': '*/*',
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest',
    'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36',
    'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
    'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
    'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
    'referer': 'https://arizonamedicalmarijuanaclinic.com/dispensaries/',
    'accept-language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9',
}

params = (
    ('action', 'wp_ajax_ninja_tables_public_action'),
    ('table_id', '42643'),
    ('target_action', 'get-all-data'),
    ('default_sorting', 'old_first'),
)

response = requests.get('https://arizonamedicalmarijuanaclinic.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', headers=headers, params=params)

print(response.status_code)

for data in response.json():
    print(data['value']['dispensaryname'])
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you had better to use a Spider and not to extract data by shell.

Also, there must a be `sleep` operation to do, because you must wait for the view to be rendered. `Selenium` or another JS driver is just useful when you must interact with the HTML (change labels, insert data, etc).

So, use `sleep` (it's not recommended) or another scrapy wait operation and, then use response.xpath(".//table") to select the table. You can follow the execution and create a for loop to recover row by row.